# Media Codec : Insufficient sized buffer

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

When i play video with resolution 704x576 (using [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html)) . I'm seeing this error and app is crashing

Logs:

```
12-04 04:35:55.507 E/OMX-VDEC-1080P( 9621): Insufficient sized buffer given for playback, expected 2514944, got 2506752
12-04 04:35:55.507 E/OMXNodeInstance( 9621): OMX_UseBuffer failed with error -2147479547 (0x80001005)
12-04 04:35:55.507 E/ACodec (22699): registering GraphicBuffer 0 with OMX IL component failed: -2147483648
12-04 04:35:55.507 E/ACodec (22699): Failed to allocate output port buffers after port reconfiguration (error 0x80000000)
12-04 04:35:55.507 E/MediaCodec(22699): Codec reported an error. (omx error 0x80001001, internalError -2147483648)
```

Comment: Did you find the solution ?

Comment: Any updates on this?